# Calling a static method in a constructor have circular dependency issue?

Tags: java, constructor, static, initialization, circular-dependency

I call class A's static method in class B's constructor and got the ExceptionInInitializerError.

Class A and B are both singleton class. I try to call A's getAInstance() method in B's constructor but got the initializer error caused by null pointer exception calling getAinstance()

```
public class B{

//B's constructor
private B(){

String res = A.getAInstance().getString();//this line cause null pointer exception

// do something

}

//static method to get B's singleton instance
public static B getBInstance(){

}
```

When I need to call B in class C, I do something like B.getBInstance().someMethodInB(). Then I cannot initialize B because of A.getAInstance() has null pointer exception. So is that a circular dependency? How to fix it? I tried to use a static block to initialize but still failed.

Comment: Provide a [mcve], please.

Comment: then `A.getAInstance()` returns `null`

Comment: Are you sure the NPE is on A.getAInstance() and not on the getString() ? And are you sure that A.getAInstance() is guaranteed not to return null?

Comment: @Andrew Tobilko Could you please tell me why it returns null?

Comment: @HenlenLee otherwise it wouldn't have thrown the exception :)

Answer (score -1):

**Example for scenario according to your explanation**

```
class A
{
    private static A a = new A();

    private A()
    {
    }

    public static A getInstance()
    {
        return a;
    }

    public void methodForA()
    {
        System.out.println("Method for A !!!!");
    }
}

class B
{
    private static B b = new B();

    private B()
    {
        A.getInstance().methodForA();
    }

    public static B getInstance()
    {
        return b;
    }

    public void methodForB()
    {
        System.out.println("Method for B !!!!");
    }
}

public class C
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        B.getInstance().methodForB();
    }
}
```

**Output:**
Method for A !!!!
Method for B !!!!

**Example for scenario with circular dependency**

```
class A
{
    private static A a = new A();

    private A()
    {
        B.getInstance().methodForB();
    }

    public static A getInstance()
    {
        return a;
    }

    public void methodForA()
    {
        System.out.println("Method for A !!!!");
    }
}

class B
{
    private static B b = new B();

    private B()
    {
        A.getInstance().methodForA();
    }

    public static B getInstance()
    {
        return b;
    }

    public void methodForB()
    {
        System.out.println("Method for B !!!!");
    }
}

public class C
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        B.getInstance().methodForB();
    }
}
```

**Output:**
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError